# Request Help for Redhat where to download MailServer-SQL.txt details below

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat, mail-server

I am currently using Redhat on AWS and setting mail server. When I up to the step that require to download this MailServer-SQL the command is:

`wget --user=sunitafe -–password=sunitafe http://tafe.mjhall.org/docs/mail-server/MailServer-SQL.txt`

because the link is my teacher server and it's been three years of course he shut it down. I can't contact him.

Anyway, the picture below is only clue I screenshot 3 years ago for evidence to submit my work. I request if anyway see the code in vi MailServer-SQL.txt below and familiar where to get it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIkXd.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0NzP.png]

Comment: When showing folks some text (errors, console IO, logs, code, config), please supply that as text and not images. There is an important reason for this: images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen-readers, which means that posts in this format do not help us in our aim of helping future readers. Would you add these things now using the formatting tool?

Comment: (Also, since this is about setting up a mail server, it is probably better on _Server Fault_ rather than here. But, the same guidance applies - supply text information in text format.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this original created the database structure and inserted defaults, as hinted in https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0NzP.png
As the table names in the screenshot indicate, it is fairly safe to assume this is
setup using Postfix and Dovecot.

Good news, you can rebuild the file.

- both Postfix and Dovecot have configuration usually in `/etc/dovecot` or `/etc/postfix` where you can also find the database configuration as well as the expected table structure, meaning: read the files, build `CREATE TABLE` statements from them
- type what is seen in the 2nd picture you posted.

Most if this stuff can also be found on the [Dovecot wiki](https://wiki.dovecot.org/FrontPage?action=show&redirect=StartSeite), or the [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this going to help much. there are a lot of folder and file in there. I will not know which file. using command to search bit by bit is a little too much for me.

Comment: In that case may I recommend this [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin)? It is a bit older but it does actually describe exactly what you are trying to do, and includes the database configuration _and_ where to find it.